# Printing wchar_t to console in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shift-jis

I have made a simple program that will read in a PS1 Memory Card binary file and display it's contents in the console using C++ in Visual Studio. The game titles are encoded in the memory in Shift-JIS format, so I used the MultiByteToWideChar function to convert them:

```
            // Converting Shift-JIS
            char lTitle[65];
            strcpy_s(lTitle, mymemcard[lFrame - 1].title);

            int lTitleChars = MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lTitle, -1, NULL, 0);
            wchar_t* lTitleL = new wchar_t[lTitleChars];
            MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lTitle, -1, lTitleL, lTitleChars);
```

My problem is now that I can't get the lTitleL variable to print to the console. I've tried cout, wcout, printf, wprintf, I can't get them to work! I know that the lTitleL variable proiperly holds the title since I can see it in the debugger. When I call any of the print functions I've tried, simply nothing gets printed.  ANy help would be appreciated! Thanks.

BIG EDIT:

OK, so here's where I am with this:

```
            // Converting Shift-JIS to UTF-8 //
            ///////////////////////////////////
            // First, convert the multi-byte Shift-JIS format into wide characters
            strcpy_s(lTitle, mymemcard[lFrame - 1].titleMB);
            lTitleChars = MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lTitle, -1, NULL, 0);
            wchar_t* lTitleFW = new wchar_t[lTitleChars];
            MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lTitle, -1, lTitleFW, lTitleChars);
            wprintf(L"FW, WriteConsoleW - ");
            WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, lTitleFW, lTitleChars, NULL, 0);
            wprintf(L"\n");
            // Memory card seems to store all characters in their "Full Width" forms, we need to convert them to Half-Width so they display nicely in the console
            wchar_t* lTitleHW = new wchar_t[lTitleChars];
            LCMapStringEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, LCMAP_HALFWIDTH, lTitleFW, lTitleChars, lTitleHW, lTitleChars, NULL, NULL, 0);
            wprintf(L"HW, WriteConsoleW - ");
            WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, lTitleHW, lTitleChars, NULL, 0);
            wprintf(L"\n");
            wprintf(L"HW, wprintf()     - %s\n", lTitleHW);
            // Now we can convert it into UTF-8 format to allow it to be printed using std::cout
            // This step isn't necessary as we could call WriteConsoleW on lTitleHW instead, but why not
            lTitleChars = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lTitleHW, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
            char* lTitleUTF = new char[lTitleChars];
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lTitleHW, -1, lTitleUTF, lTitleChars, NULL, NULL);
            strcpy_s(mymemcard[lFrame - 1].titleUTF, lTitleUTF);
            wprintf(L"UTF, wprintf()    - %S\n\n", lTitleUTF);
            delete[] lTitleFW;
            delete[] lTitleHW;
            delete[] lTitleUTF;
            ///////////////////////////////////
```

- MultiByteToWideChar to get the Shift-JIS input string into wide
  chars.
- Print that to console for debugging.
- Problem now is that the PS1 Memory Card stores all characters in their full-width forms, so I use LCMapStringEX to convert them to half-width for nicer output.
- Print that to console for debugging.
- This is enough if I am happy to use WriteConsoleW, but if not then one problem is that certain punctuations are encoded strangely and don't print nicely using std::wcout or wprintf(). For example, hyphens are stored as U+FF70 - "Halfwidth Katakana-Hiragana Prolonged Sound Mark" (after converting to  half-width) and these just show up as question marks regardless of the font being used (they do, however, print correctly using WriteConsoleW).
- So, I can now use WideCharToMultiByte, using the UTF-8 code page to get a version of the string that prints nicely to the console using std::wcout or wprintf(). I do, however, have to call both SetConsoleCP(65001) and SetConsoleOutputCP(65001) for them to print properly, otherwise the multi-byte chars (like the U+FF70 I mentioned) get printed byte-by-byte.
- Lastly, for any of the unusual characters to show up, I need to have a font selected that can display them. The only ones I have found that work in the default fonts in my console are NSimSun and SimSun-ExtB, none of the others seems to contain the Japanese characters (at least for the U+FF70 character).

To help visualise the output of this, here's a screenshot of the console using the NSimSun font:

[image]

And here with Consolas font:

[image]

Now for my question: I don't particularly like the NSimSun font, are there any others out there that look more like the Consolas font that do contain all the glyphs for the full/half width Japanese characters? If so, how can I package them into my Console app so that it's portable?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the contents of memory starting at address 0x013055d0. What do you see?

Comment: @TonyK I have replied with an edit. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about Windows, but this may depend on the encoding used in the console. In Linux, I would convert the wide chars to UTF-8 and print that result.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant here? [printf - Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=vs-2019#requirements) >The console is not supported in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps.

Comment: I've added another edit with an update to the situation.

Comment: I have added another large edit to describe current situation

Answer (score 2):

Windows has limited support for printing Unicode on console. Test your conversion by using `MessageBoxW(0, lTitleL, 0, 0)` which is guaranteed to succeed, as long as the conversion was okay.

To print to console window, you have to call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` in order to print characters out of ASCII range.

Stick with `std::wcout` or `wprintf(L"%s", str)`

There is an additional problem if the console does not support the right font. You have to try different fonts. See example below. Also consider using `std::wstring` which has automatic cleanup.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t *src = L"ABC 日本語";

    int size;
    size = WideCharToMultiByte(932, 0, src, -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string temp(size, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(932, 0, src, -1, temp.data(), size, 0, 0);

    size = MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, temp.data(), -1, 0, 0);
    std::wstring dst(size, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, temp.c_str(), -1, dst.data(), size);

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    wprintf(L"%s\n", dst.c_str());

    //Try with different font
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font = { sizeof(font) };
    HANDLE hcout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hcout, FALSE, &font);
    wcscpy_s(font.FaceName, L"MS Gothic");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hcout, FALSE, &font);
    std::wcout << dst << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmak, I will make a large edit to the question to update with my latest progress.

Comment: Edit is up now!

Comment: You shouldn't change your question like that. Please read the help section on how to ask questions. The question and answer should be in such a way that it is useful to other visitors.

Comment: I kept the original question intact. My edit provides a partial solution to the problem so is of use to future visitors and is relevant to the title of the question.

Comment: Your question was about printing Unicode, but seem to you have changed it to a question about font. I don't know if you followed my recommendation or not. I have already addressed the font option. You should post a new question about fonts, or search existing topics. `AddFontMemResourceEx` allows using fonts limited to a process, but I don't think that works for a console application, so you probably have to install a font separately.